# (Excel VBA) Parameter Not Valid (1004) Error after filter - Dynamic Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with my dynamic chart. Anytime I filter some information 
from my table, using slicer or manually, excel sends me an error message.

Parameter Not Valid (1004) Error 
on line: ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _Range(Cells(UserRow, 12), Cells(UserRow, 21))

```
Sub UpdateChart()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim UserRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Dashboard")
Set ChtObj = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 6")

UserRow = ActiveCell.Row
If UserRow < 27 Or IsEmpty(Cells(UserRow, 7)) Then
    ChtObj.Visible = False
Else
    ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
       Range(Cells(UserRow, 12), Cells(UserRow, 21))
    ChtObj.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = Cells(UserRow, 7).Text
    ChtObj.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

I call this function in my Dashboard Sheet

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1 Then
        Call UpdateChart
        ActiveCell.Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If CheckBox1 Then Call UpdateChart
End Sub
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Will you tell us at what line are you getting your error ? or should we guess ?

Comment: Sorry about that.

Range(Cells(UserRow, 12), Cells(UserRow, 21))

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line:

```
ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
       Range(Cells(UserRow, 12), Cells(UserRow, 21))
```

With:

```
ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
       "=" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(UserRow, 12), ws.Cells(UserRow, 21)).Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal)
```